# System.BadImageFormatException: Bad binary signature. in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have made an ASP.NET Core (.Net 5) Web API which works perfectly fine on my local machine. And actually all contorllers except one work fine too. When I make a Post Request to my DataStoreController I get the following exception:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Bad binary signature. (0x80131192)
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(RuntimeMethodHandleInternal
> method)    at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type
> delegateType, Object target)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression
> lambda)    at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.GetExecutor(MethodInfo
> methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor..ctor(MethodInfo
> methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo, Object[] parameterDefaultValues)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Create(MethodInfo
> methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo, Object[] parameterDefaultValues)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext
> actionContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

I have tried what would happen if I made the Method inside the Controller empty and just return null - but still the same error. The only differnce package-wise to the other controllers is that the DataStoreController uses the Stackexchange.Redis NuGet Package.

My gut feeling tells me that this is a weird Azure Bug, but I would love to get some opinions/advices/answers from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay okay. I have kind of found a solution.

I stopped and started the App Service and now everything works. This actually might be a weird Azure Issue.

Comment: I've just experienced this same error deploying a .net 6 app to Web Apps / Linux. I'd re published a couple of times. The code changes were arbitrary.  I tried your solution, and spot on. VS indicates it was restarting the app on publish, but stopping and starting the app in Azure was the fix.